# How to insert images in TextField from Django admin?

Tags: django, image

I am a django noob and have made a simple D1.6.1 blog. Now I'm wondering what is the easiest way to insert images into arbitrary positions of the blog's body from admin panel?

I hate WYSIWYG editors and had no luck with either [django-adminfile](https://github.com/carljm/django-adminfiles) or [django-filer](https://github.com/stefanfoulis/django-filer). So appreciate your fool-proof hints.

Answer (score 1):

If you aren't willing to use WYSIWYG to manage your content and have had no luck with django-filer then you will have to FTP the images to your server under your MEDIA_ROOT, insert the  tags into your body/text field and [make sure in your template that you aren't stripping tags.](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/utils/#django.utils.safestring.mark_safe)

Comment: Thanks for the hint. But using FTP each time to upload a new image is not really what I'm looking for. I was hoping that there is an alternative solution like, e.g. makrdown with an image upload button.

Comment: Upload to where? That's what `django-filer` does. Markdown doesn't have any capability to upload, it's just a markup language. You could use a *markdown editor* with an upload button but that's a WYSIWYG editor and the upload button will just be handled by an other application, i.e. django-filer. You need to figure out what you want and what part is doing what

Comment: So are you suggesting that django-filer is the best available solution for my task? I am really got confused with plethora of options to handle files here: https://www.djangopackages.com/grids/g/file-managers/

Comment: I like `django-filer` as it fits nicely into the django admin. It handles uploads of images to your server via the django admin and allows you to view them and move them around etc. You then hook up a javascript editor to the `TextField` of your blog post model in the admin. Although you might not like it, `django-tinymce` (WYSIWYG) is probably easiest as `django-filer` integrates with it.